# Android emulator error: 'Not enough memory in emulator'

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to install rsyncdroid app in my emulator using the following steps:

1. `$ ./adb push rsync /sdcard/rsync`
2. `$ ./adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system`
3. `$ ./adb shell "cat /sdcard/rsync > /system/bin/rsync"`
4. `$ ./adb shell chmod 755 /system/bin/rsync`
5. `$ ./adb shell mount -o remount,ro /system`

I'm getting stuck on step 2, which results in the error:

> ```
> cannot create /system/bin/rsync : not enough memory in emulator
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The System partition of the standard avd's have not much free space. You can start the emulator on the command line, adding the following parameter:

```
-partition-size <size>
```

alternatively you can also declare the partition size in the command line options of your android run/debug configuration in eclipse.

[image]

Comment: It still says the same. Mine is not the problem with Permission Denied. But no memory. My SDCARD size is 8192 MB

Comment: how to increase the physical memory. I have increased the SDK memory from 2Gb to 8Gb .

Comment: You can extend the physical memory in the avd Editor by adding the parameter: "Device ram size". Although though I think it has to do with the system partition size. Try my solution that I postet after the EDIT and extend the partition size during the emulator start.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I tried adding ram size parameter but it did not work.

Comment: please try the command line parameter "-partition-size" for the emulator. For me this has worked.

Comment: i tried doing this even                 $ /opt/android-sdk.../tools/android -partition-size=2048. and if wanna start emulator from command line it says. it did not recognize the word. My sdk size is 8192 Mb and my device ram size is 2048

Comment: use: `$/opt/android-sdk.../tools/emulator -avd yourAvdName -partition-size 2048`

Comment: I did this " /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator -avd /root/.android/avd/MyAndroidVirtualDevice.ini -partition-size 2048        "      But i got it as PANIC: Could not open: /root/.android/avd//root/.android/avd/MyAndroidVirtualDevice.ini.ini

Comment: Dont enter the path to the avd as -avd parameter. Just enter the name of your AVD as it shows in the android avd manager.

Comment: Hey, I got it.   emulator : Connection timed out, Proxy ignored.  What shall I do.

Comment: are you running the emulator behind a proxy server? This message I have not seen yet.

Comment: emulator: Could not connect to proxy at 192.16.3.254:8080: Connection timed out !
emulator: Proxy will be ignored !

Comment: Hey, I dont know y it is taking so much time. It almost crossed 1 hour when i executed the command (/opt/android-sdk.../tools/emulator). It is still in the way of opening only. I am not knowing whether it got stuck or still under process also. Pleassss help me out . And thanks allot for all the pain u put to reply me. I would be greatful to u

Comment: I guess if you are behind a proxy and you have configured the proxy settings in the avd manager, then this settings are ignored. You could try to interrupt the emulator (Ctrl+C in the shell) and try to add the `-http-proxy http://192.16.3.254:8080` to your emulator start command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created new AVD ?? Use SDKManager to create new AVD. and assign 1000 MB to SDCard

Comment: Hii,Thanks for the reply. Ya my SDCARD memory is 8192 MB

Comment: When I execute that cat command it says "not enough memory". And i am working in emulator